# Spine or spines?

Tags: grammatical-number

I would like to know which of the following sentences is correct:

1. His thoracic and lumbar spine were severely deformed.
2. His thoracic and lumbar spines were severely deformed.

I'm not sure whether I should use "spine" or "spines" for the above sentences. Please enlighten me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do "he" have a single spine?

Comment: It's *terrible* phrasing regardless of whether ***spine*** is singular or plural. I suggest [***The thoracic and lumbar regions***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%2B%22the+thoracic+region%22+%2B%22the+lumbar+region%22) *of his **spine** were severely deformed.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example 1 is correct. There is only one spine.

Think of it as regions of the spine and compare with "north and south Italy".

You could also use "regions of the spine" or "vertebrae".

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.